# Tips for improving performance for the following code that calculates softmax derivative

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, neural-network, julia, softmax

Edit: Added function header

```
function backward(l::SoftMax, DLDY::Array{Float64}; kwargs...)
    # credits: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79454/softmax-layer-in-a-neural-network?newreg=d1e89b443dd346ae8bccaf038a944221
    m,n =size(l.x)

    ly = Array{Float64}(n)
    for batch=1:m
      ly = l.y[batch,:]

      for i=1:n
        li = ly[i]
        l.jacobian[:,i] = -li * ly
        l.jacobian[i,i] = li*(1-li)
      end

      # l.jacobian = ly'.*repmat(ly, 1, n)
      # for i=1:n
      #   li = l.y[batch,i]
      #   l.jacobian[i,i] = li*(1.0-li)
      # end

      # # n x 1 = n x n * n x 1
      l.dldx[batch,:] = l.jacobian * DLDY[batch,:]
    end

    return l.dldx

end
```

Above is my code for the backward function of my softmax layer. The way of computing softmax derivative is described nicely by the answer in this thread https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79454/softmax-layer-in-a-neural-network?newreg=d1e89b443dd346ae8bccaf038a944221. Here, I'm looking for a more efficient way to compute the derivative, as the code above takes `0.05~6` seconds to evaluate a 1000 by 100, whereas the previous softmax+cross entropy combined layer takes only `0.002` seconds.

I am thus looking for a way to make the code run faster. I'm not sure if I'm using the most efficient way of computing the jacobian matrix, but I've tried another way where I `repmat(ly,1,n)` and then dot multiply it with `ly`. That turns out to be even worse since apparently julia's `repmat` takes too many allocations.

Essentially, I'm looking for a efficient way to multiply an array with each element in the array, and concat the results into a square matrix. Does any julia master have an idea on this? Thanks!

Comment: It is much easier to answer questions about speed if there is code which is running (slowly, I guess) in the question. If you add runnable code, the response is usually quick.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to show my "runnable" code here, as it's relatively huge and complicated. Besides the part really makes the code slow is literally calling the function `backward`, which I put on the question. I believe what I'm trying to achieve in the function should be relatively obvious and in the mean time I also tried my best to describe in words. As I also said in the original post the second loop `i=1:n` is what takes the most time, and is the major part I'am for optimization by posting the code here. If you have any question about my code I am also happy to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After complaining about runnable code (the complaint is still relevant), I'll try a more constructive remark. Replace the loop:

```
 for i=1:n
    li = ly[i]
    l.jacobian[:,i] = -li * ly
    l.jacobian[i,i] = li*(1-li)
 end
```

With (no looping necessary):

```
 l.jacobian .= -ly .* ly'
 l.jacobian[diagind(jacobian)] .= ly.*(1.0.-ly)
```

The resulting `l.jacobian` should be the same, and it is more efficient.

As for an explanation, the key features used are: dot notation for `broadcast` and `diagind`.

Comment: That indeed made the code faster! The backward function now runs for average `0.03` seconds, which is almost twice faster than previous. I'll now look for a way to cancel out the outer loop `for batch1:m` to try to make it even faster! Thanks for your constructive advice on using the `.=` operation!

Comment: Seems it should be possible to improve the outer loop. If you ask another question on StackOverflow about it and include a function and a few lines to make a demo run of it, you could get a faster response or at least a better one in terms of votes ;)